# Merge existing Microsoft Account into new 365 Account

Tags: account-management, office-365

I've had a Microsoft Account with my own name@company.com email address for a few years. I've used this for Bing & Skype. We've now moved our company over to Office 365 so my name@company.com exists there too.

These accounts have different passwords and different personal details. How can I merge my existing Microsoft Account into my new Microsoft 365 Account?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot. I know this all too well since I have 1/2 dozen or so various Microsoft and enterprise accounts & it is thoroughly confusing!